# Change Split Screen Expanding Color Android

Tags: android, split-screen-multitasking

When in the Clock app AND in split screen mode AND expanding, the background color of the expanding part is blue like the rest of the app. I'm referring to the part circled in red.

[image: Clock app expanding part]

In my app the expanding part color is white, how can I change it to a custom color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this this by setting the window's background.

In your xml style:

```
<style name="YourTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/your_color</item>
</style>
```

Or you can do it programmatically:

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.your_color);
```